# Google BigQuery extract string from column with regexp_extract - string value

Tags: google-bigquery

I know there's similar question, but in my case the solution didn't work since there's no valid delimiter.

I have a string inside a column:

`{"module-version": "2.0", "more-details-link": ""}, "has-cve": true, "issue-package": "VM-Essentials", "legacy-scan-status": "removed"}`

I need the inside of issue-package. I tried:
 `REGEXP_EXTRACT(details_issues.issue_raw,r'\"issue-package=(.+?)\,')`

But i'm getting Null inside the column. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a JSON string, you should use [JSON_*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_or_json_extract_scalar) functions instead.

You can try something like:

```
JSON_EXTRACT(details_issues.issue_raw, '$.issue-package')
```